# What is the difference between with and without () symbol in creating an instance of an object in C#?

Tags: c#, class, instance

I have a class **Product**

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Could you please help me to explain the difference between two case of creating the instance of **Product** class below?

```
var instanceOne = new Product
{
    Name = "iPhone 4"
}
```

and

```
var instanceTwo = new Product()
{
    Name = "iPhone 5"
}
```

Thanks

Comment: These kind of thing can be easily verified with SharpLab https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgdgpgLgZgHgGiiAlgGwD4AEBMBGAWAChisBmAAlyrwHZiBvYgSHKpwoAUAnAewBMArgGMoLJkWatKWPAAYKAOQCGAWwgtmEqcwDm0ANybmAZ0OaAviyslJuHOM0A3ZdwoowJqMrDCIAeUgKAF4KSAB3Lj4hUQYVdRCKACIUTgALXiCAFiSLI0lmFzcPLx8/ABVw3kSIqIERKAAKAEo4tQhElPTMjpy862ILIA as you can see, the generated IL for both case is identical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, they're the same (assuming you meant to initialize the `Name` property, not define it, and it can't be static), except for one very specific case:

```
Product instanceOne = new()
{
    Name = "arf"
};
```

If you use type-targetted `new`, you have to use the `new() {...}` version, because `new {...}` defines an anonymous type instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Yes, that's my question, i have edited my question

Answer (score 0):

The `()` is redundant in the following example:

```
var instanceTwo = new Product()
{
    Name = "iPhone 5"
}
```

You can just write:

```
var instanceTwo = new Product // <----- () deleted
{
    Name = "iPhone 5"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference between these two.

Please note that [object initalisers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#object-initializers) allow specifying constructor parameters too.

```cs
class Cat 
{
    public Cat() {}

    public Cat(string name) { Name = name; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }
}

(...)

var lightning = new Cat(Name: "Lightning")
{
    Color = "White"
};

var storm = new Cat
{
    Name = "Storm",
    Color = "Gray"
};
```

## A tiny bit more

Please also note that

```
var storm = new Cat
{
    Name = "Storm",
    Color = "Gray"
};
```

is not the same as

```
var storm = new Cat();
storm.Name = "Storm";
storm.Color = "Gray";
```

The former results in:

```
var __a = new Cat();
__a.Name = "Storm";
__a.Color = "Gray"; 
var storm = __a;
```

as shown in [Overview of C# 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb308966(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#2641-object-initializers).